# extract basic count per values using the chunksize parameter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a CSV file with the following categories: `item1`,`item2`,`item3`,`item4` which values is exactly one of the following: `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`.
I would like to count for each items how many are there for each value.
My code is the following, df being the corresponding DataFrame:

```
outputDf = pandas.DataFrame()
cat_list = list(df.columns.values)
for col in cat_list:
        s = df.groupby(col).size()
        outputDf[col] = s
```

I would like to do exactly the same using the `chunksize` parameter when I read my CSV with `read_csv`, because my CSV is very big.
My problem is: I can't find a way to find the `cat_list`, neither to build the `outputDf`.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd apply `value_counts` columnwise rather than doing `groupby`:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("basic.csv", usecols=["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"])
>>> df.apply(pd.value_counts)
   item1  item2  item3  item4
0     17     26     17     20
1     21     21     22     19
2     17     18     22     23
3     24     14     20     24
4     21     21     19     14
```

And for the chunked version, we just need to assemble the parts (making sure to `fillna(0)` so that if a part doesn't have a 3, for example, we get 0 and not `nan`.)

```
>>> df_iter = pd.read_csv("basic.csv", usecols=["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"], chunksize=10)
>>> sum(c.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0) for c in df_iter)
   item1  item2  item3  item4
0     17     26     17     20
1     21     21     22     19
2     17     18     22     23
3     24     14     20     24
4     21     21     19     14
```

(Of course, in practice you'd probably want to use as large a `chunksize` as you can get away with.)