# value_counts() in heavy/large data files python/pandas/unix

Tags: python, pandas, unix, large-data, large-files

I have multiple *.txt heavy files (~ 200 GB each) and I am trying to count the values in a certain column ('val'). I used python pandas for this casebut i am happy to use unix or any faster method.

```
file = pd.read_csv('example1.txt', sep = '\t')
    print(file['val'].value_counts())
```

However, I got a message 'Killed' or that the memory limit has been used.

Any suggestion to do my job when using heavy files?

Comment: Use the chunksize argument and process them in smaller chunks? The value counts are just additive

Comment: Thanks, I have tried: 'file = pd.read_csv('example1.txt', sep = '\t', chunksize=10)
sum(c.apply(file['val'].value_counts()) for c in file)'  but got an error: TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You might want to check out dask https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/ it should help solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for a faster method you could try [tsv-summarize](https://ebay.github.io/tsv-utils/docs/tool_reference/tsv-summarize.html), one of the tools in [eBay's TSV Utilities](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils). The tools are intended for large files and are quite fast. Pre-built binaries are available for unix and macs. Here's an example generating counts for unique values in a column:

```
$ # Command line to tab-separate values
$ echo $'aa\txx\nbb\tzz\naa\txx'
aa  xx
bb  zz
aa  xx

$ # tsv-summarize command to generate counts for values in column 2
$ echo $'aa\txx\nbb\tzz\naa\txx' | tsv-summarize --group-by 2 --count
xx  2
zz  1
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

This is working at the moment:

```
result = pd.concat([ chunk.apply(pd.Series.value_counts) for chunk in pd.read_csv('example1.txt',sep = '\t',chunksize=5, usecols=[2]) ] )
print(result.groupby(result.index).sum())
```

Modified from: [extract basic count per values using the chunksize parameter in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25428661/extract-basic-count-per-values-using-the-chunksize-parameter-in-pandas)